# fetch td with exact text with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, parsing

I want to find the next td value of a td (this td wil be defined with a text). here is my html

**Matrikel:**
                9 EC , TORUP BY                               **Grundareal:**
                        454              
              
                **Ejendomsværdi:**
                    860.000                **Grundværdi:**
                    313.500

*** Now I need the td where "Ejendomsværdi:" contains and then go to next td to get value.
how I can do this?

*** the format creates problem, so I can explain the table structure.
here "Ejendomsværdi:" is td value and next td value is  "860.000" but "Ejendomsværdi:" td is wraped with fond and bold element. any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('td:contains("Ejendomsværdi")').next().text()
```

Comment: thanks, but it is not working. let me describe details. I have a table which has 5 rows and each row has 4 columns. 5th row, 1st column is "<td><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><b>arefin:</b></font></td>" and 5th row , 2nd column is "<td height="20">    860.000</td> ". Now I want to get the 860.000 value. do you have any idea? I have already tried , but not success.

Comment: @AhmadNaqibulArefin Can you post your markup? you had posted your markup at fist and it worked for me!!

Comment: <tbody><tr>
                <td height="20"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">arefin:</font></td>
                <td height="20">    860.000</td>                <td height="20"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><b>Grundværdi:</b></font></td>
                <td height="20">    313.500</td>              </tr>
              
              <tr>
                <td colspan="5"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"></font>  </td>              </tr>
             
             
            </tbody>
​

Comment: here is the markup, please see .. @undefined. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Problem is solved according to your way, I had wrong markup. Forgot to add table element before tbody in test phase. Thanks a lot.